# Issue in reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

```
struct A
{
   uint8_t hello[3]; 
};

struct B
{
    const struct C* hello;
};

struct C
{
    uint8_t hi[3];
};

B.hello = &reinterpret_cast<C &>(A);
```

Assume that I have filled the structure `A` with values `1`, `2`, `3`.
If I print `B.hello.hi[0]`, I get `0`. Instead, I should have got `1`.
Am I doing casting wrong?

I have checked the values of struct `A` right above the `reinterpret_cast` line in my code and it prints ok, so I don't think I have any issue in storing the values in `A`. It is just the conversion which is causing the issue.

Comment: *Instead, I should have got 1* - Why? Take a look at the [list of valid conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) that `reinterpret_cast` can do and think which bullet applies to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casts work on instances not classes, so you need to cast an instance of A not A itself

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cassert>

struct A
{
    uint8_t hello[3];
};

struct B
{
    const struct C* hello;
};

struct C
{
    uint8_t hi[3];
};


int main()
{
    A a{}; 
    a.hello[0] = 1;
    a.hello[1] = 2;
    a.hello[2] = 3;

    B b{};
    b.hello = reinterpret_cast<C*>(&a);
    auto hi = b.hello->hi;
    assert(hi[2] == 3);
}
```

Comment: This is sheer undefined behaviour. [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Comment: I agree it is undefine. It is not something I would do either, but the question was about the cast. Not if it was smart to wite code like this (which it isn't).  ;)